# django - any prebuilt authentication signal receivers?

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

I'm writing a custom logout view since the Django built in logout function wipes out all the sessions when it calls the request.session.flush(). I have some sessions variables that I would like to keep even though the user has logged out.

I was thinking to use a signal to notify all the web site that I've logged out.
Does the Django 1.2.4 authentication system  have any built signal receivers to send a signal to so the other pages on the web site will be "informed" that I've logged out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Django 1.2.4 doesn't provide authentication signals, but they were added in trunk, so the next release probably will include them.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//topics/auth/#login-and-logout-signals